# Is there anything I need to be mindful of when I have multiple interview from same company but different roles?

Tags: interviewing, internship

I have received 3 co-op interviews from same companies,each with different programmer-related role. It is a big cooperation(Top 15 according to Forbes). However, I have no idea if any of these roles are in the same department. So I feel like it will be kinda awkward to interview same people twice in the row especially I am planning to schedule these three interviews in the same day(Is it a good practice?).

So my questions are :

1. Given the information I have, is this a good practice to schedule all three interviews in the same day?
2. is there any other rules about having multiple interviews from same company?

Comment: The interviewers might be aware of your three interviews or not. In any case, you should be prepared to answer questions about this. E.g., they might ask which position you would prefer. (I've interviewed someone twice in a day. They got one of the jobs.)

Comment: I'm in a similar situation and I'm concerned about the overlap between two interviews I have this week with the same company, and possibly department. There was a big gap between me applying for them and I didn't feel like I would get both. I've had one interview and I've got another to go to tomorrow. What happened in your situation? Do you have any advice now you've gone through the process? Would you recommend mentioning it to the employer?

Comment: @fey, I am really sorry, I just saw this. I hope your interview went fine. For me, the person who interviewed me was really cool about it. I asked him after my interview and he said that it happens all the time.

Comment: No worries - thanks for getting back to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> good practice to schedule all three interviews in the same day?

No, like any meeting,you should prepare for each individually if possible and focus entirely on it.

> any other rules

No, if asked just tell them you have applied elsewhere, it's normal enough for someone job hunting. But usually it won't be asked.